# sorting by has_one assosiation fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an model "Event" which have assosiation

```
has_one :movie
```

and time column.
Movie model have a lot of fields: name, rating, actors and other
I want to create table of Events, and in this table i want colums to be sortable by fields of Movie model. Can you advise way of doing this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```
Event.joins(:movie).order("movies.name")
```